# WSO2 Identity Server, Spring Security and OpenID attributes

Tags: spring-security, wso2, openid, attribute-exchange, wso2-identity-server

I have a webapplication using spring security. I'd like to login using an account i have configured on the WSO2 identity server using OpenID.

I can login just fine, the identity server asks for the password and redirects me back to my webapplication. So far, so good. However, when i try to request additional attributes using the attribute-exchange, i get empty values.

I have tried a few different types:

```
schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname
axschema.org/namePerson/first
urn:scim:schemas:core:1.0:name.givenName
schema.openid.net/2007/05/claims/nickname
wso2.org/claims/givenname
```

But none of them seem to yield any results.

Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be the fields are empty as well. 
Can you try with the following claim URI, http://wso2.org/claims/role. By default all users have the everyone role. So that value should be returned.